# CSS Tab - hide child content on first load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a tab system, that seems to work nicely in my CMS; however, I'm having difficulty in hiding the children content areas when it is first loaded. Once you click on the tabs - then it hides the content. What am I missing?

```js
(function($) {

  var tabs = $(".tabs li a");

  tabs.click(function() {
    var content = this.hash.replace('/', '');
    tabs.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#content").find('p').hide();
    $(content).fadeIn(200);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="tabs group">
    <li>
      <a class="active" href="#/one">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/two" id="tabs2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/three" id="tabs3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="content">
    <p id="one" style="clear: both;"><strong>Product Summary 1</strong><br>
      <br>
      <strong>Lorem ipsum 1</strong><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis,
      mi.<br>
      <br></p>
    <p id="two"><strong>Product Summary 2</strong><br>
      <br>
      <strong>Lorem ipsum 2</strong><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis,
      mi.<br>
      <br></p>
    <p id="three"><strong>Product Summary 3</strong><br>
      <br>
      <strong>Lorem ipsum 3</strong><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis,
      mi.<br>
      <br></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Due to our CMS I have very little movement on the code I can write as TinyMCE WYSIWYG will strip the majority of code out. So the HTML above is pretty much all it will show, whist I can add the JQuery and CSS in another section of the CMS.

You will see a working example with all HTML, JQuery and CSS in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Studio1st/shv3rxn7/5/).

I know it's going to be something stupid and I'll probably beat myself around the head, when someone assists - but I would appriciate the help.

Many thanks

Comment: working example link is not showing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#two, #three{
  display:none;
}
```

to the bottom of your stylesheet.
https://jsfiddle.net/shv3rxn7/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1u8m8pko/

```js
$('#content p').hide();

$('.tabs li a').click(function(){
  $('#' + $(this).data('id')).slideDown().siblings('p').slideUp();
});

$('.tabs li a').first().trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
<ul class="tabs group">
    <li>
        <a href="#/one" data-id="one">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/two" data-id="two" id="tabs2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/three" data-id="three" id="tabs3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <p id="one" style="clear: both;"><strong>Product Summary 1</strong><br>
    <br>
    <strong>Lorem ipsum 1</strong><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus,
    nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi.<br>
    <br></p>
    <p id="two"><strong>Product Summary 2</strong><br>
    <br>
    <strong>Lorem ipsum 2</strong><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus,
    nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi.<br>
    <br></p>
    <p id="three"><strong>Product Summary 3</strong><br>
    <br>
    <strong>Lorem ipsum 3</strong><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus,
    nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tempus, nunc nec efficitur facilisis, mi.<br>
    <br></p>
</div>
```

I've added `data-id` i.e. data-attribute to anchor tags(tabs).

Added jQuery click event to get `data-id`. Using jQuery I've triggered a click for first tab.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Shiladitya - sadly data-id gets stripped out of my code. But thank you and also a good resolve.